# Using Custom name for Return key

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use custom name for Return Key instead of already specified in Xcode

what is the right way to do that in swift , please advise ?

Comment: hmmm....That's sad to know that there is now way to do that ..thanks for reply ...

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, **Swift** and **Xcode** do not offer us this possibility. The predefined labels you can choose from for the return key are:
`Return, Go, Join, Google, Route, Next, Send, Search, Yahoo, Done and Continue`.

The only possibility for you would be creating a custom input field (aka some buttons on a view) where you put your own titles to those buttons.